# how to sum the values from table based on id and save it to another table without creating duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I have  table name called spent_table where user will add the amount he as spent.

[image]

I want to sum all the values in spent_amt field based on the id and it should save the values to another table total_table without creating duplicate values in it.
It should update the fields whenever new value entered in spent_table

Comment: Hi, what is the unique value in `spent_amt` "employee_name"??

Comment: Give me some more explanation on what you should achieve??

Comment: @Chethan Jagannatha Kulkarni     every time when a user enters the spent amount its has to calculate the total amount of his spent amount and save it to another table.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't store this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use mysql trigger to do it.

this is a good [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) how to do it. hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO total_table (employee_name, total) SELECT * FROM (SELECT employee_name, SUM(spent_amt) FROM spent_table GROUP BY employee_name) AS temp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = VALUES(total)`

assuming that `employee_name` is unique value in table `total_table` and `total` is a column in `total_table` to keep sums of spent amounts

Comment: The values will be saved to a table but it create duplicate value. I dnt want duplicate values do u knw any solution?

Comment: @Rock it should not create duplicate value. make sure that employee_name or whatever is unique index